# Call function inside SCons Builder's action

Tags: scons

I'm trying to write a Builder in SCons to call a command line executable with some arguments that are generated by a (series of) python functions.

```
cmdVars = Variables(None, ARGUMENTS)
cmdVars.AddVariables(
    EnumVariable('DEBUG', 'help for debug', 'a', allowed_values=('a','b','c')),
    PathVariable('CLI', 'path to cli exe', 'C:\...\blah.exe', PathVariable.PathIsFile)
)

env = Environment(variables = cmdVars)

def generateSomeExtraBitsDependingOnFlag(debug):
    if (debug == 'a'):
         return "-DDEBUG -DBlah myTextHere"
    return ''

myBuilder = Builder(
    action = '"$CLI" generateSomeExtraBitsDependingOnFlag("$DEBUG")'
)

<extra stuff to add myBuilder to env and call env.myBuilder>
```

The "$CLI" input is correctly substituted to output (when calling scons) something like `C:\Program Files\...\blah.exe` but the output from the function never appears, regardless of the `DEBUG` setting.

Prepending `print(debug)` inside the function prints `$DEBUG` whilst parsing the SConstruct file (so it's not surprising it doesn't match the if condition).

Do I just need to use a **[Generator](https://scons.org/doc/HTML/scons-user/ch18s05.html)** or follow the instructions in chapter 18.4 (**[Builders That Execute Python Functions](https://scons.org/doc/HTML/scons-user/ch18s04.html)**) to make this work? Is the section **[Writing Builders That Execute External Commands](https://scons.org/doc/HTML/scons-user/ch18.html)** not what I want here?

I suspect that given understanding, the user guide is clear, but without already knowing the answer, the guide is a little opaque to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
cmdVars = Variables(None, ARGUMENTS)
cmdVars.AddVariables(
    EnumVariable('DEBUG', 'help for debug', 'a', allowed_values=('a','b','c')),
    PathVariable('CLI', 'path to cli exe', 'C:\...\blah.exe', PathVariable.PathIsFile)
)

env = Environment(variables = cmdVars)

def generateSomeExtraBitsDependingOnFlag(source, target, env, for_signature):
    if (env['DEBUG'] == 'a'):
         return "-DDEBUG -DBlah myTextHere"
    return ''


env['generateSomeExtraBitsDependingOnFlag'] =generateSomeExtraBitsDependingOnFlag

myBuilder = env.Builder(
    action = '"$CLI" ${generateSomeExtraBitsDependingOnFlag}'
)

env.Append(BUILDERS = {'myBuilder' : myBuilder})

env.myBuilder('dummy','input')
```

Comment: It looks like this is basically the same ideas as the generator discussed in Ch 18.5 (or at least, the function has the same signature). Is there a benefit to using the function in this way (i.e. in a Builder's `action`, rather than its `generator`)?

Comment: You can use the ${generateSomeExtraBitsDependingOnFlag} in any command line. Instead of just one..  or use it as part of CPPFLAGS, etc..